# Set Views page title based on content being viewed via contextual filter

Tags: 8, views

I have a view page that shows a single node based on a contextual filter that looks at an aliased path version of the title. For example my URL might be
http://www.tacoland.com/resources/npr-story-about-tacos

and I want to set the page title to be NPR Story About Tacos (the node title).

I see how I can change the title with the value from the URL within the contextual filter settings, but I want it to be the proper node title.

My issue is basically like this one, but for D8: [Views Page Title Based on URL](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/154180/views-page-title-based-on-url)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Add Title as field

  - ☑️ Checkmark exclude from display
- For view title, put `{{ title }}`

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response, but unfortunately that doesn't work.

Comment: I tested it... thats how I got the screenshot.

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry. I was just coming back here to say I realized I still had a value in the override title section of the contextual filter.

Comment: Any idea why I'm still seeing {{ title }} for the breadcrumb on this page?

Comment: That's due to a bug in core, try applying [the patch](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2787051) in comment #44 for D8.

Comment: Thanks... I actually ended up faking it by creating a block display based on the original view that shows the title and then rewriting the output of the title field with the markup for the breadcrumbs.